# What does 4{signal} mean when signal is a 4-bit wire?

Tags: verilog

What is the meaning of `{4{update}}` in such statement:

```
wire [3:0] update;
assign signal = {4{update}} & anothersignal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the free IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 11.4.12.1 *Replication operator*.

`{4{update}}` is the same as concatenating the 4-bit signal 4 times:

```
{update[3:0], update[3:0], update[3:0], update[3:0]}
```

The result is a 16-bit signal.